# Como acessar sistemas de um servidor local por outras máquinas

Tags: php, redes, localhost, easyphp

Tenho uma máquina rodando vários sistemas através do `EasyPHP5.2.10`, porém, ao tentar acessar esses sistemas através de outra máquina substituindo o `localhost` pelo endereço da minha máquina, as páginas não abrem.

Vi que existem algumas alterações que tem que ser feitas nos arquivos de configuração do `php` e do apache, o `php.ini` e o `http.conf` para fazer aparecer a página do `easyphp` abrir quando o endereço da sua máquina é pesquisado no navegador. Mas isso já acontece.

Quando eu digito o endereço da minha máquina, abre aquela tela do easyphp com a pasta de todos os sistemas. Alguns abrem, outros não mesmo que não tenha nenhuma diferença entre eles.

Eu já tentei liberar a porta 80 do firewall e não deu certo.

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Essa é a página que o usuário de outra máquina vê:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não criou exatamente essa pergunta dias atrás e fecharam como duplicata? Poderia explicar o porquê de não ser duplicata e que te fez refazer a pergunta? Aliás, a frase "*alguns abrem, outros não*" ficou extremamente vaga. Quais abrem? Quais não? Qual a diferença entre eles? Você fez o que a pergunta que sinalizaram como duplicata recomendava, para liberar o seu servidor na rede?

Comment: Eu removi a pergunta e refiz porque certamente não era uma duplicata já que nenhuma das questões "duplicatas" da minha resolvia a minha questão. Como a pergunta que eu fiz já não tinha movimentação e estava classificada como duplicata de outra pergunta que não resolve meu problema, achei melhor recriar.

Comment: Eu criei todos os sistemas exatamente da mesma forma, a única diferença era o template, logo, todos deveriam ou abrir ou não abrir, mas alguns abrem e outros não. Já procurei e não encontrei nenhuma diferença entre eles.

Comment: Todos são PHP? Utiliza algum framework? Os projetos possuem o arquivo `.htaccess`? O que aparece no histórico de log do servidor ao acessar os projetos que não abrem corretamente?

Comment: Todos são `php`, uso `bootstrap` pra maioria mas o sistema que eu não uso `bootstrap` é o que abre.

Comment: E os logs? Qual é a tela que aparece nesses que não abrem corretamente? Há mensagens no console? E na aba network, tem algo estranho?

Comment: Nenhum dos sistemas tem a .htaccess, vou colocar na pergunta uma imagem da página que o usuário vê. Não tem nada no console

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80875/discussion-between-mariana-ferreira-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que fazer algumas alterações no seu arquivo httpd.conf.

- Acrescentar o seu endereço de IP logo abaixo ao endereço IP do localhost

> ```
> #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
> Listen 127.0.0.1:80 (padrao)
> Listen 192.....:80 (IP do seu servidor)
> ```

- Altere as configurações de acesso aos diretórios abaixo comentando as linhas **Allow from 127.0.0.1** e **Deny from all** e acrescente a linha **Allow from all** como no exemplo.

> ```
> <Directory "C:/../binaries/home/images_easyphp">
>         Options Indexes MultiViews
>         AllowOverride None
>         Order deny,allow
>         #Allow from 127.0.0.1
>         #Deny from all
>         Allow from all
>         Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "C:/../binaries/home">
>         Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
>         AllowOverride None
>         Order deny,allow
>         #Allow from 127.0.0.1
>         #Deny from all
>         Allow from all
>         Require all granted       
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "C:/../Webserver/modules">
>         Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
>         AllowOverride All
>         Order deny,allow
>         #Allow from 127.0.0.1
>         #Deny from all
>         Allow from all
>         Require all granted       
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: Então, eu já tinha tentado fazer isso e realmente abre a minha página do `easyphp` em qualquer computador, porém, nem todos os sistemas que tem lá dentro abrem.

Comment: Mas essa é uma resposta válida pra ajudar pessoas que tenham um problema parecido.